# Div "margin-top" is relative to body instead of parent div

Tags: html, css

The HTML for my page:

```css
#header {
  background-color: #0cf;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 29%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 9%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="menu">
    this is menu
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the "#menu" has its margin relative to "body" element I want its margin to be relative  to "#header".

You can probably see that i am creating a fluid grid here, and margin of my "#menu" div should be relative to the "#header" otherwise it will not work(see the screen shots).

Here are the screenshots.
First one at resolution of 1024*768.

Second is at resolution of 1280*1024

[image: 1024*768]

[image: 1280*1024]

In second screenshot the "#menu" is a little high from the bottom of "#header".

My question is how can i apply a margin which changes as the height of "#header" changes?

I have already read about the "margin collapsing" thing but i don't think this is what's happening here,as my parent div has a border.

Comment: _“The problem is that the "#menu" has its margin relative to "body" element”_ – are you talking of the _amount_ of margin that the percentage value results in? _“I have already read about the "margin collapsing" thing but i don't think this is what's happening here,as my parent div has a border”_ – because it has a border, the margin-top of the inner element is “kept inside”, otherwise it would be combined with the margin of the outer element, so that the latter would have a margin-top.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: When your header is 70%, you want your margin to be 30%. And when your header is 60%, you want your margin to be 40%? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes exactly.if height of #head translates to 700px for a specific resolution and margin of #menu to 20px. i want margin of "#menu" to be 18px for 600px height of "#head"

Comment: Then I probably would solve it with JavaScript...

Comment: Ok so you are saying that there is no pure CSS solution for my problem?:(

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this problem by using:

```css
position:absolute;
top: xxx px; /* (or bottom, left, right) */
```

Comment: Yes i think it'll work maybe there is a better solution.I normally avoid using absolute positioning as it takes away the whole flexibility and can make things look ugly.

Comment: Basically, you're right. That's why, I do it like example:
'position: absolute;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;'
Also tried other ways, but this is what works reliable. Beside of this, the most of users are not interested in how to do, just care about the result. That's why, we have to try to make our life more easy.

Answer (score 0):

the 9% that you used in `#menu { margin-top: 9%; }` means 9% of ducument size which is all maximum browser window .

use `position:relative` for both #header and #menu . then give `top:9%` to #menu .

Answer (score 0):

The percentage height property in CSS **can only** be applied to elemets whose parent's have a position other than static.

Just add `position: relative` to `#header` and you should good to go!